# How can navigate to a fragment from dialog fragment using navigation graph - Android

Tags: navigation, uinavigationcontroller, navgraph

I have a dialog fragment and fragment and I am using navigation graph in the application, And for switching between fragments, I am using actions. So here, I want to direct a user to home screen when he clicks on 'OK' button from a popup (created by dialog fragment class). But there is no option to specify the attribute for dialog fragments in navigation xml file. And for fragments I have added like below screen shot.
[image]

So my question is, how can write an action from dialog fragment to home fragment using navigation graph in Android?